# DB2 Z/os Native SQL Procedures -- Updated

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, procedure, zos

I'm implementing a DB2 Native SQL procedure.  It's the first we've tried this in this shop.  I've attached the code below.  What this routine does is keep track of the number of new records added to a table by time.  Whenever it fires, it either updates a record in the monitoring table or inserts a record if the table doesn't exist.

Native procedures are new to Z/os db2 version 9.

The redbook on procedures for Z/os db2 v9 reads:
"Figure 15-15 depicts the DB2 components involved when a native SQL procedure is called
either from a remote application, a DB2 attached program, or an allied address space
respectively. As illustrated, the SQL statements are no longer executed in an external WLM
address space but natively in the database system services address space. For execution,
the procedure packages are loaded into the EDM pool."

Yet, If I remove the line "WLM ENVIRONMENT FOR DEBUG MODE DSNDSPENV" from the code, I get an error saying the "WLM Environment must be specified".

Does anyone know a reason that WLM dependency might exist with this code?  Do I need to override a WLM_ENVIRONMENT default?  And if so, how would I do that?

---

New Information--------------------------------------------------------

---

It appears that if you add the option "DISABLE DEBUG MODE" you are not required to specify a WLM for DEBUG.

What's the downside of disabling debug mode?  Is there any downside to leaving a procedure in "ALLOW DEBUG MODE"?  Is there overhead to using a procedure in which debug can be allowed?

---

```
--#SET TERMINATOR !                                            
 CREATE PROCEDURE $172.VQT_QUOTE_INFO_COUNT_NEW_QUOTE(
                      IN RATING_STATE CHAR(2),
                      IN INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP)
 LANGUAGE SQL
 ALLOW DEBUG MODE
 WLM ENVIRONMENT FOR DEBUG MODE DSNDSPENV                 
 BEGIN
   DECLARE NO_RECORD_UPDATED INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
      SET NO_RECORD_UPDATED = 1;
  UPDATE  $172.VKT_MONITORING_COUNTS
     SET MC_QUOTE_CNT = MC_QUOTE_CNT + 1
  WHERE MC_STATE_ABBREV = RATING_STATE AND
        MC_SAMPLE_DATE = DATE(INSERT_TIMESTAMP) AND
        MC_SAMPLE_HOUR = HOUR(INSERT_TIMESTAMP);
  IF NO_RECORD_UPDATED = 1    THEN
  INSERT INTO $172.VKT_MONITORING_COUNTS (
              MC_STATE_ABBREV, MC_SAMPLE_DATE, MC_SAMPLE_HOUR,
              MC_QUOTE_CNT, MC_NEW_POLICY_CNT)            
         VALUES.                                                
              (RATING_STATE, DATE(INSERT_TIMESTAMP),
               HOUR(INSERT_TIMESTAMP),  1, 0);               
 END IF;
 END.#
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

Answer (score 0):

WLM stands for Work Load Manager.

The work load manager (which is part of the base z/OS) is responsable for allocating memory and other resources and running your script.

Each WLM environment will run scripts at different priorities and have its own settings for maximum time to run, maximum cpu consumption and its own set of rules about which resources can be accessed.

Comment: Nice description of WLM.  In version 9.1 of Z/os DB2, we can avoid using WLM altogether with procedures by creating native procedures.  However, if one wishes to do debugging at some point, a WLM will need to be specified, even though in normal operation it would not be used.  In some environments, enabling debugging means additional info needs to be kept in the symbol table and you have slightly bloated code with a minor performance impact.  Does enabling debugging in DB2 have any downside for native procedures?